# Java NIO connect to socket

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to connect to a remote server and send a login message in my Thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        address = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        incomingMessageSelector = Selector.open();
        socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();           
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        socketChannel.connect(address);
        socketChannel.register(incomingMessageSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        serverManager.loginToServer();
    }
}
```

the loginServer() is a method which send a message to ther server but i keep getting an:

```
java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException
```

how can i check and wait for connection before sending this loginServer() method?

Comment: I would suggest you initially implement using blocking NIO. Its much simpler and may do what you want. Note: In NIO, the default behaviour is blocking.

Answer (score 12):

If you're connecting in non-blocking mode you should:

- register the channel for `OP_CONNECT`
- when it fires call `finishConnect()`
- if that returns true, deregister `OP_CONNECT` and register `OP_READ` or `OP_WRITE` depending on what you want to do next
- if it returns false, do nothing, keep selecting
- if either `connect()` or `finishConnect()` throws an exception, close the channel and try again or forget about it or tell the user or whatever is appropriate.

If you don't want to do anything until the channel connects, do the connect in blocking mode and go into non-blocking mode when the connect succeeds.

Answer (score -1):

i've found an answer.. i should use:

```
    socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(address);            
    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

    while (!socketChannel.finishConnect());

   //my code after connection
```

because the NIO is in not blocking mode we have to wait until it finish its connection

Comment: This is pointless. Just do the connect in blocking mode and avoid smoking the CPU. Or else register OP_CONNECT and use select() and call finishConnect() when it fires.